# how to retrieve negative data from different column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

i have data like this,
[data orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDYqi.png)

> I have to select any sub-category that has a negative profit

the data has 9000+ rows

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post some sample data and what you've tried so far as text/code, not images?

Answer (score 0):

Something like `df.loc[df["Profits"] < 0]` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to select all the rows from your dataframe where the value in column Profit is negative (<0)

Assuming you are using a pandas dataframe named df. The following code should gives you all the Sub-Category where at least one row within the Sub-Category had negative profit.

```
df[(df.Profits < 0)]['Sub-Category'].unique()
```

You may want to first import your data to pandas. Assuming your data is stored in 'path/to/data/data.csv'

```
import pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/data/data.csv')
```